# Error while programming on FPGA

Tags: xilinx

I'm programming on `fpga` but it is giving the following error:

> ERROR:EDK:3165 - elfcheck failed!
>
> The following sections did not fit into Processor BRAM memory:
>     Section .boot (0x0 - 0x3)

Try using the linker script generation tools to generate an ELF that maps
correctly to your hardware design.
Programming the `FPGA` failed due to errors from `elfcheck`

I increased the `BRAM` memory but it's still giving the same error.

Comment: Are you sure your BRAM memory is mapped to the address 0x0?

Comment: What is the size of the program? What is the size of the BRAM? This usually happens when your program is too big to fit in the available memory.

Comment: Dmitry, how can i check memory mapping.

Comment: Jonathan, my bitstream is not loading to fpga.